# Eclipse Relative Layout is hard to work

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

I don't know if you guys use this type of layout for most times but it drives me crazy. 
 
for example when I put a button in the middle of screen and then put a textview near button suddenly IDE reorders them and textview goes on top and button on right. 
 
it can make problems when using too many elements on screen. 
since that time I use linear layout but it also has some limitations. 
 
Thanks, I'm new into android development (4 days starting to learn) so I hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 3):

I rarely use RelativeLayout to be the main layout of a activity. It is recommended to use LinearLayout and set `android:weightSum` so your app could have a larger support for the screens. As you know there's a huge variety of devices running Android with different screen sizes. Use RelativeLayout only if you want that view in that specific place with that fixed size.

See this example of using LinearLayouts to create a activity with many elements, as your refered:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
android:weightSum="3"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/picker_time_hour"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/picker_time_hour_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hours"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/picker_time_hour_up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="+" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/picker_time_hour_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/picker_time_hour_down"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="-" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/picker_time_minute"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/picker_time_minute_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/minutes"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/picker_time_minute_up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="+" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/picker_time_minute_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/picker_time_minute_down"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="-" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/picker_time_second"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/picker_time_second_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/seconds"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/picker_time_second_up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="+" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/picker_time_second_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/picker_time_second_down"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="-" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the result is:

[image]

As you can see my opinion is that you should use LinearLayouts, but [read this topic](http://logc.at/2011/10/18/when-to-use-linearlayout-vs-relativelayout/), it can also help you choosing.

Comment: thanks, I happened to hear there are external programs with drag&drop ui builder and they export result in XML. do you know one?

Comment: I've heard about [Codiqa](http://www.codiqa.com/), but it's not free. I create the layouts by code. I know at the beggining people tend to use drag&drop ui builders but when you have a little more experience you'll be more confortable to work by code. But is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Relative Layout has proven the most often used Layout for me. Besides the fact that is really customizable (although maybe is less straightforward than LinearLayout) it is also quite "fast". "Fast" means that there is a certain overhead when you use nested LinearLayouts,that you can avoid by using a RelativeLayout. Specifically:

> Sticking to the basic features is unfortunately not the most efficient
>   way to create user interfaces. A common example is the abuse of
>   LinearLayout, which leads to a proliferation of views in the view
>   hierarchy. Every view — or worse, every layout manager — that you add
>   to your application comes at a cost: initialization, layout and
>   drawing become slower. The layout pass can be especially expensive
>   when you nest several LinearLayout that use the weight parameter,
>   which requires the child to be measured twice.

Comment: You are right, I was hoping it be more of A visual studio UI Editor type ,which is fast ,easy and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

To my experience, you should not use the eclipse drag&drop ui builder. It will cause only confusion and problems. It's not yet mature enough (even if it has made a great progress in the last years).

Especially as a beginner, you should work directly with the xml. This will give you a much better understanding of the layouting mechanisms. I don't know a single android developer, who is seriously working with the ide builder.